# which pattern groups these sublists together

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule

I have a sequence given below:

```
seq = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6,2},
{7, 3}, {8, 4}, {9, 2}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10,5}, {11, 2}}
```

I split the list according to the first element

```
splitlist = SplitBy[seq, First]
{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 2}}, {{5,1}},
{{6, 2}}, {{7, 3}}, {{8, 4}}, {{9, 2}}, {{10, 2}, {10,3}, {10, 4}, {10, 5}}, {{11, 2}}}
```

then decreasing the brackets by 1

```
splitlist //. {x_} :> x

{{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6,2}, {7, 3},
{8, 4}, {9,2}, {{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 5}}, {11, 2}}
```

Now i wish to find a repeated rule (//.) such that i can group all the consecutive lists of 2 elements together into a single list i.e. {... {{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6,2}, {7, 3},{8, 4}, {9,2}} ....}

```
{{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, 

{{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6,2}, {7, 3},{8, 4}, {9,2}},

{{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 5}}, {11, 2}}
```

Any pattern that can group sublists of elements 2 when they appear consecutively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to group the consecutive pairs (`{_Integer, _Integer}`) at at the first level. Is that correct? In that case, this should probably do the trick:

```
FixedPoint[
  Replace[#,
    {x1___, 
     x : Longest @ Repeated[{_Integer, _Integer}, {2, \[Infinity]}], 
     x2___} :> {x1, {x}, x2},
    {0}
  ]&,
  {{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2},
   {7,3}, {8, 4}, {9, 2}, {{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 5}}, {11, 2}}
]
```

If you want to apply this at lower levels, you can change the level spec of the `Replace`. If you want to find other elements that are not lists (instead of just `_Integer`), you can go with something like `{Except[_List], Except[_List]}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. it works for a larger set. I was making a mistake :)

Comment: btw, please replace x1__ (two underscores) to x1___ (three underscores) and x2__ to x2___ to take care of end cases because for a list like `{{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2},
   {7,3}, {8, 4}, {9, 2}, {{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 5}}, {11, 2},{12,4}} ` your current implementation will give trouble

Comment: Thanks Ali, you're completely correct. I adapted the answer as such.

Answer (score 5):

One step back to go two steps forward:

```
Split[splitlist, Length @ #1 == Length @ #2 == 1 &] //. {x_} :> x
```

> {{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 
>      2}, {7, 3}, {8, 4}, {9, 2}}, {{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 
>      5}}, {11, 2}}

---

To use `PartitionRagged`, for fun:

```
parts = Length /@ Split[Length /@ splitlist, #1 == #2 == 1 &]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1}

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[splitlist, parts] //. {x_} :> x
```

> {{1, 2}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 
>      2}, {7, 3}, {8, 4}, {9, 2}}, {{10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {10, 
>      5}}, {11, 2}}